# Ubuntu Server How to delete timezone

Tags: server, date, timezone

[image: Double Timezone picture]

I try to set my timezone to asia/kuala lumpur.

But it came out with 2 timezones, how do I delete the universal timezone?

Comment: What command did you use that got that output?  Normally that's just there for a time reference to compare against other timezones or clocks, such as UTC, and not actually the case of 'two timezones'.

Comment: That comes from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime and that command is run to update the timezone data from the `/etc/timezone` file.  Showing the UTC is normal and nothing to worry about.  UTC is technically not a timezone, but a reference point that all timezones are based off of.

Comment: actually i was trying to set my nfsen timezone, apparently after i set the timezone on ubuntu, i need to restart cron, apache2 and nfsen to apply to my nfsen.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong there. The command is just printing the UTC time for verification. Usually, in Ubuntu, the system clock is assumed to be in UTC and the timezone information is used to adjust the time w.r.t. UTC for applications. You don't need to worry about the UTC time.